# mod_python for python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-python

I recently downloaded python 2.7 on my computer (x64) and I would like to install mod_python for it (I have apache 2.2), however, I can't find a mod_python release supporting python 2.7. Has development stopped? If so, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Development on mod_python has stopped and its use is no longer recommended. I suggest [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)

From the [mod_python Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/modpython/):

> Support for mod_python has been deprecated, and will be removed in Django 1.5. If you are configuring a new deployment, you are strongly encouraged to consider using mod_wsgi or any of the other supported servers.

Comment: @Manfre I djangobook still mentioning mod_python .. why?

Comment: @Surya djangobook only covers up to Django 1.0. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/modpython/